# Disadvantages of passing around functions?

Tags: c++, class, function, mutable

I'm learning C++ (coming from java) and recently discovered that you can pass functions around. This is really cool and I think immensely useful. Now I was thinking on how I could use this and one of the idea's that popped into my head was a completely customizable class.

The best example of my train of though for completely customizable classes (code) would be say a person class. Person would have all functions pertaining to P. Later Person may pick up a sword (S), so now Person has access to all functions pertaining to both P and S.

Are there limits or performance issues with this? Is this sloppy and just plain frowned upon?

Any insight is educational, thanks.

~Aedon

Comment: FWIW: In Java the same thing is simulated with passing around objects with a given nominative type. For instance, a Thread can be passed a Runnable "function" (well, instance of an object that only has one "Run" method). Languages like C# and Scala hide this detail (but still pass around functions as sugar over objects).

Comment: In java however, you have to hard code the definition into the class (well you could also modify the class on the fly, but you would have to recompile before you could use the new code, if i'm not mistaken). Can you not just pass a function variable to a class and execute the function in c++? With out having to hard code the... I guess type?

Comment: You can do it. Should you do it? almost always no. The trick is knowing when you should.

Comment: Could you inform me why? Just bad form?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA The definition of the class has to be hard-coded, just as the definition of the function must be (excluding "magic" run-time generation). Otherwise, both are treatable as objects (of different sorts) and are both assignable.

Comment: Just try to do it, and you will soon see that being able to pass functions around is not the same as creating new classes with extended functionality, there are just so many things that you can do with that...

Comment: @unapersson - what do you think will not be type-checked at compile-time when using function pointers or functors?

Comment: Minor point of nit-pickery:  You don't really "pass around functions."  You pass around function pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight performance hit since a pointer or reference must be dereferenced before calling the function.

This is a very advantageous feature.  Many design patterns and polymorphism depend on pointers to functions.  Check out the "Visitor Design Pattern".

Another usage is for a table of functions.  For example, you could write a generic menu engine that displays different menus by using different functions.

Also research "Factory design pattern."

Answer (score 4):

When passing around functions - i.e. pointers to functions really - calls are always indirect and therefore possibly slower than a direct call (and definitely slower than an inlined call altogether).

The STL is modeled with *functors*. That is: light function objects that have a operator() member which gets called. This has the advantage of being a very likely candidate for inlining, especially if the functor and `operator()` are very simple (as e.g. `std::less<T>`).

See also: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/functors.html

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with passing around a function, but it's kind of primitive and limiting. Often you have some data that you want to associate with the function, in addition to the parameters you're passing to it. Also you might want to group related functions together and pass them as one. Congratulations, you've just described a C++ class!

If you want to see how C++ can really blur the line, consider a functor. This is a class that has an `operator()` method, so that you can call it just as you would a function. It has two immediate advantages over a plain function: it can hold state between calls, and it can be inlined by the compiler for superior performance. It's not uncommon for `std::sort` to outperform the older C `qsort` for example, because `qsort` uses a function pointer while `std::sort` uses a functor.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into functor's.